# Eulerian Paths Question

Tags: eulerian-path

I have been asked to state whether the below graph is Eulerian or Hamiltonian, and to give an appropriate trail/cycle.

[image]

I believe it is Eulerian as each vertex, (Indicated by the red dots) have an even degree of edges. However I am not able to find a suitable trail, (A route beginning and ending at the same vertex using all the edges once) does this mean the graph is not Eulerian and is in fact Hamiltonian?

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Try the following route: $1\to 2 \to 6 \to 3 \to 1 \to 4 \to 6 \to 5 \to 1$

Comment: Thank you, I was under the impression that you could only go through each vertex once, however I re-read this to be each edge only once.